# What is a sourced shell function?

Tags: bash, nvm

In the nvm [README.markdown](https://github.com/creationix/nvm/blob/master/README.markdown) it says

> Please note that `which nvm` will not work, since `nvm` is a sourced shell
>   function, not an executable binary.

What I found is the nvm install process will update the `.bashrc` with

```
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
```

Somehow this makes the `nvm` command available to the shell. My question is what is a "sourced shell function" and what exactly does the command nvm execute?

Comment: If you want to know what the function named `nvm` does, run `type nvm` to print its text after it's been defined

Comment: BTW, I'm assuming in my answer that you know what a shell function is in general. The question presently doesn't make it clear whether that assumption is well-founded.

Comment: Aside: If bash-specific, `nvm.sh` is misnamed and should be instead `nvm.bash`; while using `.sh` generically is [rather unfortunate in the best of times](https://www.talisman.org/~erlkonig/documents/commandname-extensions-considered-harmful/), it's outright harmful when it's falsely implying compatibility with other POSIX shells -- ksh, dash, ash, etc -- for a script that, not being invoked through a shebang, can't specify its own interpreter.

Comment: (It's actually common, for something intended to be sourced, to see several versions alongside each other with different extensions: a `foo.ksh`, a `foo.bash`, a `foo.csh`, etc, with versions compatible with different shells)

Comment: Interesting! running `type nvm` provides the following output: `nvm is a shell function from ~/.nvm/nvm.sh`. I'm just learning that shell functions are a way to group commands which can be executed later using a single name for the group. If my understanding is in order, in this case, the name for the group is `nvm` and the commands have been grouped in the source script `nvm.sh`.

Comment: As far as I know, `bash` is an acronym for *b*ourne-*a*gain shell, a reference to the fact that bash is an enhanced replacement for `sh`, the original Unix shell program written by Steve Bourne. I'm guessing that's mainly why it's rather inappropriate to name shell scripts using the `.sh` extension.

Comment: @danmaze, ...there are some intermediate steps in the history that you're missing. Bash is indeed a play on the name of the Bourne shell, but it's not _compatible with_ the 1970s-era original Bourne shell. Instead, it's compatible with the early-1990s POSIX sh standard while also pulling in a lot of features from 1980s-era ksh, often with compatible syntax. There's code that works in 1970s Bourne that doesn't work in bash; code that works in 1991 POSIX sh that doesn't work in 1970s Bourne, and _a whole lot_ of features in modern bash that Bourne doesn't have.

Comment: @danmaze, ...on systems that comply with the POSIX standard, `sh` isn't Bourne but rather POSIX sh; the last operating system I knew to ship Bourne was SunOS, and they finally stopped in the mid 2000s.

Comment: @danmaze Back when I started in the 90s, the way GNU autoconf distinguished between Bourne shell and POSIX sh was running `echo hello ^ cat` (in a script with history expansion disabled), because original Bourne treated `^` as a pipe character. If it writes `hello ^ cat` it's POSIX, if it writes `hello` it's Bourne.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This verbiage is sloppy. `nvm` is simply a shell function defined by sourcing the file in which that function is defined. That doesn't change the function in any qualitative way: It would be the same function, with all the same behaviors, if you'd typed it in by hand, so applying "sourced" as a modifier is a bit misleading; it would be more accurate to say that `nvm.sh` is a sourced script which defines a shell function named `nvm`.

---

As for the specific syntax:

```
. somefile
```

is the more portable way to write

```
source somefile
```

...which performs the actions in `somefile` *within the current shell*, as opposed to within a separate shell run as a subprocess.

Thus, sourcing a script can modify your current interpreter -- setting variables, changing its working directory, and, yes, defining aliases and functions -- in ways that executing an external program cannot.

---

To clarify: If you ran `bash somefile`, then any functions defined by `somefile` exist only for the duration of that particular copy of `bash` -- when it exited and returned you to your prompt, functions defined in `somefile` would no longer be available. By contrast, when you `source somefile`, because the contents of `somefile` are executed in your current shell instance, those contents are able to persist.

Comment: The effect of sourcing a script is *almost* identical to that of typing every command in it into your interactive shell by hand. Thus, if you can define a function by typing it into your command line, you can define that function by sourcing a script that contains its definition.

Comment: Makes sense, feel embarrassed it didn't occur to me :(

Comment: *nvm.sh is a sourced script which defines a shell function named nvm*: This makes much more sense. If it had been worded more clearly and accurately in this way, it would have been easier to understand.